# How many ways can two pizzas be chosen from 4 sizes and 8 toppings

Tags: combinatorics

You are ordering two pizzas. A pizza can be small, medium, large, or extra large, with
any combination of 8 possible toppings (getting no toppings is allowed, as is getting all
8). How many possibilities are there for your two pizzas?

The no of ways of ordering the pizza is (since the order does not matter but replacements are allowed):
$$P_p= \binom{4+2-1}{2} = \binom{5}{2}=10$$

And the 8 toppings (including the no toppings options could be chosen in): $$P_t= \sum_{k=0}^8 \binom{8}{k}$$

And the solution is $P_p*P_t$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: How did you get 5C2 again? I don't get that step.

Comment: Bose Einstein value $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$...chosing k objects from n when order does not matter but replacements are legit and yes the pizzas can be of the same size and toppings

Comment: If I do $\binom {4}{2}$ then I exclude the possibility of the two pizzas being the same size

Comment: @Orpheus Where does it state the two pizzas can't be of the same size?

Comment: It does not state that the pizzas cannot be of the same size...they could be the same size...that is why replacements are allowed hence the formula $$\binom{n+k-1}{k}$$

Comment: for the case where I chose two pizzas that are same..I mean identical...should I consider that as 1 way of chosing it...

Comment: Ohh yeah...thanks a lot @Math Lover...so I just multiply 10 by 256

Comment: how is that possible....is it $256^2 * 10$

Comment: Given so many comments, I have moved the details in my answer now. Pls check.

Comment: @Deepak [why picking 2 items from 4 categories can be done in $^5C_2$ ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3860757/21813)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of ways to select sizes for two pizzas $ = {5 \choose 2} \,$ (as the order does not matter but replacements are allowed).

Number of ways to select toppings on a pizza $ = 2^8 = 256$ as you can choose each topping independently (either it is selected or not selected).

So far your workings is correct. Now split the cases as follows -

i) where two pizzas are of different sizes - as both pizzas are of different sizes, they are distinct and hence total number of possible toppings choices  $ = 256 \times 256$.

Example - say you have chosen $(S, M)$ pizza sizes and say you have choice of only one topping - pineapple (P or N - none). Then one pizza has $2$ combinations of toppings and so two of them have $2^2 = 4$ different combinations. $(S - P, M - P), (S - P, M - N), (S - N, M - P), (S - N, M - N)$.

ii) Both pizzas are of the same size - now there is no distinction between them and hence it is a case where the order does not matter but replacements are allowed. So total number of choices of toppings on a pizza should be extended to two pizzas in this fashion.

Total number of cases where both pizzas are of same size $= 4 \, (S, M, L, XL)$.

Total number of cases where both pizzas are of different sizes $ = 10 - 4 = 6$.

i) Number of combinations $ = 6 \times 256^2$

ii) Number of combinations $ = 4 \times {257 \choose 2}$

So total number of combinations $ = i) + ii) = 524800$.

EDIT: or you can simply look at it as $1024$ possibilities for a pizza and when you extend it to two pizzas where order does not matter but replacements are possible.

So total number of combinations = $ {{1024 + 2 - 1} \choose 2} = 524800$

Comment: so basically in the second case...you considered two identical pizzas (which would be the stars) with 256 ways of choosing the toppings(which would be the bars)...

Comment: @orpheus yes that is correct. There are simpler ways to look at it too. I could take total number of possibilities for one pizza and could extend it to the second. See my EDIT for example.

Comment: Thank you @ Math Lover...I get it now!