# In how many ways can 15 identical math books be distributed to six students?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations, multisets

question: In how many ways can 15 identical math books be distributed to six students?
i try do this: P(15,6) could be this the answer or i should check the question, i find out other? help please

Comment: This problem can also be reframed as [picking r=15 items from n=6 categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3860757/21813). This elaborates on @Parcly's stars-and-bars suggestion

Comment: And for the unasked alternative of adding the constraint that each student must get at least one book, the altered problem bijects to $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_6 = 9$, which has $\binom{9 + 5}{5}$ solutions.  See https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not solved by a permutation because the books are identical. This is a stars-and-bars problem, with $15$ stars (the books) and $5$ bars creating six spaces for the six different students. The answer is therefore $\binom{15+5}5=\binom{20}5$.

Answer (score 0):

One particular distribution of the $15$ identical books to $6$ students could be

$$B B B | B B | B B B | B B | B B B | B B$$

Note that this has needed $5$ dividers, and these could be placed anywhere in the configuration of $15 + 5 = 20$ symbols.
Thus the number of ways of distributing them = ${20}\choose 5$